# Проверка существования элемента списка зная его итератор

Tags: c++, списки

Как проверить, существует ли элемент списка, зная его итератор, чтобы программа не вылетала при его отсутствии?

```
list<int> myList; // объявляем пустой список
for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
    myList.push_back(i);
list<int>::iterator it = myList.begin();
    advance(it, 20);
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае происходит `advance` за границы контейнера, что есть UB. Так что может быть все, что угодно - в том числе вполне корректный итератор, указывающий на что-то в контейнере.

В общем случае - никак: может, у вас вообще итератор от другого контейнера :)

Так же, как в общем случае нельзя ничего сказать о корректности значения произвольного указателя.

Comment: Тогда есть какой-либо способ обратиться к элементу иным образом(не через advance), чтобы после можно было проверить его существование?

Comment: Вы не могли бы сформулировать конкретнее, что именно вас интересует? Делайте тот же `advance`, но не больше чем на `size`... В чем ваша проблема?